# ActiveAdmin: Apply default theme styles to custom partial for custom panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin for my project. I wanna have a custom panel for an index page. The problem is I dont know how to apply default ActiveAdmin style my custom partial. Currently it's style is broken

[image: Broken Active Admin UI]

I want the statistic / summary part to be inside the `Summary` panel and have better format like simple table

Below is my code

```
ActiveAdmin.register UserAnswer do
  config.per_page = 1

  index do
    panel "Summary" do
      render partial: "summary"
    end

    column :answer do |u_answer|
      link_to u_answer.answer.content, [ :admin, u_answer.answer]
    end

    actions
  end
end
```

I just want to add basic table inside the `summary` panel

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h3>Total Attempts</h3></td>
      <td><h3>100</h3></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><h3>Answers</h3></td>
      <td>
        <h3>Answer 1: Chosen 1000 times</h3>
        <h3>Answer 2: Chosen 1000 times</h3>
        <h3>Answer 3: Chosen 1000 times</h3>
        <h3>Answer 4: Chosen 1000 times</h3>
        <h3>Answer 5: Chosen 1000 times</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
  panel "Summary" do
    content do
      render partial: 'summary'
    end
  end
```

As anything rendered within content will be the main content on the page. Partials behave exactly the same way as they do for resources.

Please checkout [this](https://activeadmin.info/10-custom-pages.html) for more reference.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the code hide all the partial, nothing shown in the summary part

Comment: Is your summary partial is in `app/views/admin/user_answer/_summary.html.arb`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why trying to add table into a panel mess the UI up. I come up a solution by just putting the table alone and merge its table head to make it as a normal panel header and add the class `index_table` to the table

The final code will be

```
<table class="index_table" style="margin-top: 100px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Summary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h3>Total Attempts</h3></td>
      <td><h3><%= UserAnswer.count %> </h3></td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And, no more using `panel`

```
ActiveAdmin.register UserAnswer do
  config.per_page = 1

  index do
    render partial: "summary"

    column :answer do |u_answer|
      link_to u_answer.answer.content, [ :admin, u_answer.answer]
    end

    actions
  end
end
```